# What's the standard max width for CSS

Tags: css

So I want the css to change when the user makes the window just a few tens of  pixels smaller. But I don't know what's the width I need to use.
My monitor is 1440x900, but other people have 1920x1080... and let's not forget about the 4K monitors.
What's the width that I put here?

```
    @media screen and (max-width:.....?){}
```

Comment: _What's the width that I put here?_ only you can answer that. What device/screen width is your CSS targeting?

Comment: if you have `@media screen and max-width:800{}`, `@media screen and max-width:1920{}` etc, then `@media screen {}`, will handle anything above your biggest width rule, so 1920

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the best result when you make sure the page looks good on every width, not just specific resolutions. That means you start to decrease the window width, and when it looks bad, that's when you add your media query to change something. The moment when it starts to look bad is different on every website. Although if you find yourself having to add a new breakpoint every 20 pixels, chances are media queries are not the solution to your problem.

If you want to test it on higher resolutions than your monitor, you can use for example Chrome's device toolbar to set a custom resolution for the viewport.

Commonly used breakpoints might be the ones bootstrap uses: 991px (tablet) and 767px (mobile). Although that's not necessarily what makes sense to use in your website.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: @media is encapsulating your CSS. That means, if you don't use it - your CSS will be global unless it is overwritten.

Now, you can use multiple @media queries, so you can make your site look good on different devices. Although **it should be designed well, so you don't need to write @media for every 100 px change**.

If you don't have a specific need, you can follow Twitter Bootstrap pattern:

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) { }
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) { }
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) { }
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) { }
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not planning on adding 100 media queries. It's just that I have 2 rows of iframes that are very close to the window borders, and when I make it just a little bit smaller they start to look bad. I have to make it at least 600 pixels smaller for the site to look bad again.
I will probably use only 2 media queries. Maybe 3, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

The @media query is 1/3 of the recipe for responsive design. It is the key ingredient that, in it's simplest form, allows specified CSS to be applied depending on the device and whether it matches the media query criteria.

**All popular breakpoints is given below**

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { /* Styles */ }

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) { /* Styles */ }

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) { /* Styles */ }
```